# What did I wrong?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

```
public Cursor getChart(String sign ) {
    return db.query(CHART_TABLE, new String[] { 
            KEY_CHART_ID,
            KEY_SIGN,
            KEY_TOTAL },
            KEY_SIGN + "=" + sign, 
            null, null, null, null, null);
}

05-09 17:14:39.260: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14935): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "+": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, sign, total FROM ChartTable WHERE sign=+
```

Comment: "WHERE sign=+" and 'do' wrong..

Comment: As a first pass KEY_SIGN + "='" + sign +"'",

Comment: 05-09 17:23:33.740: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16664): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Answer (score 3):

Wrong way to query database. Try this ..

```
public Cursor getChart(String sign ) {
    return db.query(CHART_TABLE, new String[] { 
            KEY_CHART_ID,
            KEY_SIGN,
            KEY_TOTAL },
            "KEY_SIGN =?", new String[]{sign}, 
            null, null, null);
}
```